# "real" baseline for typography

Tags: html, css, typography, baseline

Line-height in web design and line-height in print (InDesign and more) is not the same.
Result is near :

- In web http://jsfiddle.net/Y9M28/4/ (better in webkit)
- In print http://jsfiddle.net/Y9M28/3/

I try a lot of tricks but as you see in my print sample, the last paragraph make a bad margin due to multilines.
Is it possible to do it better for modern browser ? 
I know http://baselinecss.com/ but this is with a lot of relative position and top adjustement not really flexible.

A last solution would be to add javascript for separate multiline block in many single line (but to heavy).

Comment: I looked in to this a lot a year ago, ended up having to supply position critical typography as images to the browser, as it varies so much with font handling between the different browsers, could not get it consistent.

Comment: @Orbling After some experimentation, here is the trick!
http://b4d455.fr/basel/

Comment: Looks interesting, will have to study it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` is only working on **inline** elements and **table cells**. `<p>` is a **block** element.
The default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

You might have better success in your experiment knowing this. Good Luck!

[This is a great article that explain `vertical-align`.](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

[And here is the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align)